# How can I save an unpublished node skipping required fields validation?

Tags: 8, nodes, forms

What is the best way to save node without the required field values?

It would be something like "save as unpublished" and the required validation is omitted, but I am not sure in which module I can find this functionality and how to set it up.

Comment: Sounds like core's Content Moderation and a custom submit handler maybe. Have you had a look at Content Moderation already and if it can be accomplished using it?

Comment: This sounds like you are solving the wrong problem: Your fields are obviously not required, it is the publishing state that requires that certain fields are not null. Instead of making a hack-ish "maybe sometimes required" field, I'd write a [custom form validation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183685/how-do-i-add-a-custom-validation-handler-to-an-existing-form-field) for the publish/status field.

Comment: @NoSssweat I need to skip required fields on an edit form. Something like saving a draft before it can be published.

Comment: @leymannx Yes, I took a quick look at it, but haven't succeeded yet to save, because it makes an ajax validation on the required fields when saving as a draft

Answer (score 4):

I finally solved this using the [Require on Publish](https://www.drupal.org/project/require_on_publish) module. It offers an additional checkbox to require only when publishing the node.

> This module allows fields to be required only when the piece of
> content is being published or is already published. This can be used
> when you have fields such as tags or SEO information on your piece of
> content that editors really don't need to fill in until the content is
> going live.